# How can I execute a shell script file by the MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to execute my x-report.js file using MongoTemplate and get Collections(output for displaying in UI). I tried in many ways, but i didn't find any solution.

```
  StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            new ClassPathResource("x-report.js").getFile()));
    try {
        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            text.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        try { br.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
    obj.append("$eval", text.toString());
    System.out.println(mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj));
```

Am using Mongo 3.2.0 version, But $eval has been removed in MongoDB 3+ version. Then i tried with "command"

```
   com.mongodb.DB mongoDb = mongoTemplate.getDb();
    CommandResult cr = mongoDb.command(mongoScript());
    System.out.println("Command Restults------->" + cr.size());


private String mongoScript() {
    String st = "db.ReportData.find({\"createdDate\": {$gte:ISODate(\"2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z\"), $lte:ISODate(\"2017-04-20T00:00:00.000Z\")}})";
    return st;
}
```

In this way also i am unable to execute my script. Please someone help me.

Comment: Hi I guess this link can help you http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.server-side-scripts